# How will i do probability in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on a game. I want to do something like 50% of the time it shows you are lucky today here is $100 and 50% of the time it should say better luck next time. Can anyone please guide me how can i do this? I am using eclipse and java.
I have this so far:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
            int per = 0;
            per = GenerateRandom.getRandom(2);
                        if (per<50)
                        {"better luck next time"}
                        else
                        {"you won $100"}
}
```

Is this right way to do? Or is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - no, that's not quite the way to do it.  You would want to make use of the [`Random`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html) class in Android to generate pseudo-random numbers.  (You can learn more about PRNGs [here](http://www.random.org).)

In my mind, the best way to do this (from a practical Java standpoint is to use code similar to the following:

```
public String isLucky() {
    Random ran = new Random() * 100; // Generates values between 0 and 100 exclusive
    return ran <= 49 ? "Better luck next time!" : "You win $100!"
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard Java way of generating a random number is from [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29). This method returns a floating-point number between 0 and 1. You can convert this to any range of numbers with:

```
int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range + lowerBound);
```

Where `range` is the number of numbers that you want to pick from, and `lowerBound` is the smallest number you want chosen. In your case, you only want to choose between 0 and 1 for a 50% chance. Your code will look like this:

```
public string foo()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
        if (rand == 0) {
            return "better luck next time";
        } else {
            return "you won $100";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question. If i want to do 25% and 75% how will that be different?

Comment: Your percentages are multiples of 25, so you'd want 4 possible values to choose from - 0, 1, 2, and 3. If you wanted 75%, you would check `if rand <= 2`. What the other answer does is choose from 100 different numbers 0-99. This works on any scale though. If you wanted, say, 37.48%, you would pick a range of 10,000 and check `if rand <= 3748`